# Best practice to initialize values in views after OnCreate

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have some problems initializing some values for some views in my Android Activities cause for me to be able to get the views I have to wait for the activity layout aswell as the fragment layout to be inflated until I can initialize the views values. I know i can initialize the views in the fragments OnCreateView but I would like to avoid that and instead have some kind of method that is run right after the onCreates/onCreateView's are done.

Is this possible if so how? And what is the best practice of modifying/initializing views?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a special case you should not deviate from the lifecycle of a `Fragment` or `Activity`.
Anyway if so, Calling a method as you asked for, look at the MainActivity class on [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/) example. It uses a `Handler` to do work on the UI Thread

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the `onStart()` or `onResume()` methods, which are called after `onCreate()`, but also after stopping or pausing of the Activity.

For more detailed Information have a look at [the Activity Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

You should also try to work on the formatting of your question, I'm not sure whether I understand the problem correctly, or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the way mentioned over [here](http://android-activities.blogspot.in/2013/11/cleaner-view-casting-with-generics.html). It's cleaner.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer : "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score -2):

you put the following method in the fragment.

> public void initFragment() {   //Do your required things here }

After creating the object for the fragment (for instance example given below)

> mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
>         mIssDetailsListFragment = (IssDetailsListFragment) mFragmentManager
>                 .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_outlet_list);

you call the method **initFragment()** (Sample code given below)

> mIssDetailsListFragment.initFragment()